# Probability distribution Problem for finding the number of occurrences of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Problem:**

[image: Probability Problem]

**MyApproach:**

After finding the probability for X=4,5,6 using bernoulli trials,the question states that they are in ap and so find the value of n.I can't understand the relation between ap and finding the value of n.

**NOTE:**

*multiple answers are correct*

Comment: I suppose a.p. means 'arithmethic progression'. It mens that $\mathbb P(X=5)-\mathbb P(X=4)=\mathbb P(X=6)-\mathbb P(X=5)$.

Comment: yes i am getting your point.Please continue.

Comment: Well...suppose $n=7$.  Then the probability that $X=\{4,5,6\}$ is $\{0.2734375,0.1640625,0.0546875\}$  so the difference are both $-0.109375$.  Hence that choice works, and so on.

Comment: what do you mean by difference in both.What are the two numbers between which you are finding the difference.

Comment: Between the comment of @Fimpellizieri and mine you have more or less a complete solution (at least for $n=7$ but the other cases are similar).  Please try to work through those comments on your own.

Comment: Can i post my answer here?Is allowed in the community?

Comment: Absolutely!  It's even encouraged.  We'll review your answer for completeness and accuracy.

Comment: Please go through my answer.I also wanted to know whether i can ask and answer my own questions in this community.I would also provide my research work.

Answer (score 0):

For $0\leq k \leq n$ we have

$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\binom{n}k\,p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$$

where $p$ is the probability of the coin coming up heads.
In our case, the coin is fair, so $p=\frac12$ and the expression reduces to $\mathbb P(X=k)=\binom{n}k\,2^{-n}$.
We hence need to look for solution to

$$\binom{n}5\,2^{-n}-\binom{n}4\,2^{-n}=\binom{n}6\,2^{-n}-\binom{n}5\,2^{-n}$$

which simplifies to

$$\binom{n}5-\binom{n}4=\binom{n}6-\binom{n}5.$$

Consider the following manipulations:

\begin{align}
&2\,\binom{n}{5}=\binom{n}6+\binom{n}4\\
\iff &4\,\binom{n}{5}=\left(\binom{n}6+\binom{n}5\right)+\left(\binom{n}5+\binom{n}4\right)\\
\iff &4\,\binom{n}{5}=\binom{n+1}6+\binom{n+1}5\\
\iff &4\,\binom{n}{5}=\binom{n+2}6\\
\iff &4\,\frac{n!}{5!\,(n-5)!}=\frac{(n+2)!}{6!\,(n-4)!}\\
\iff &4=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{6(n-4)}\\
\iff &24(n-4)=(n+2)(n+1)
\end{align}

At this point, it's a matter of checking against the given options.

If you want a more analytical route, you can observe that $n+2$ and $n+1$ are always coprime, so they cannot share any prime divisors of $24=8\times 3$.
In particular, we must have one of

1. $n+2$ is a multiple of $3$ and $n+1$ is a multiple of $8$; or
2. $n+1$ is a multiple of $3$ and $n+2$ is a multiple of $16$.

Notice that if $n+2$ is a multiple of $8$, then $n$ is even and hence $n-4$ is also even, which justifies (2).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

*I posted this answer after getting help from the users of the mathematics stackexchange community.I was provided some hints from the users in the comment sections which helped me to come to this conclusion.*

**Solution:**

[image: Solution to my Problem]

Comment: I would say that this is incomplete...you essentially assert the answer with no explanation.  Moreover, you do not say whether $7,14$ are the only solutions or even if they are the only solutions from amongst the given list of options.  Did you proceed by trial and error or did you change the indentity you found between binomial coefficients into a polynomial equation for $n$?

Comment: okay.You may edit my answer if you want or post a complete solution of your own.